# Fill SvelteKit style with dynamic value

Tags: sveltekit

I'd like to fill css in  with values from my  section. Is that possible?

Here's an example of a component I'd like to create using this feaure:

```
<script>
    import {
        mdiLinkedin,
        mdiEmail,
        mdiCakeVariant,
        mdiMapMarker,
        mdiPhone,
        mdiWeb,
        mdiSkype
    } from '@mdi/js';

    function getIcon(prop) {
        switch (prop) {
            case 'contact.LnProfile':
                return mdiLinkedin;
            case 'contact.Email':
                return mdiEmail;
            case 'contact.Address' :
                return mdiMapMarker;
            case 'contact.Birthday' :
                return mdiCakeVariant;
            case 'Phone' :
                return mdiPhone;
            case 'Website' :
                return mdiWeb;
            case 'IM' :
                return mdiSkype;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    export let prop, color = 'white', size = '24px';
    let iconPath = getIcon(prop, color);
</script>

{#if iconPath}
    <span class='dynamicClass'>
        <svg viewBox={`0 0 24 24`}>
            <path d={iconPath} />
        </svg>
    </span>
{/if}

<style>
    .dynamicClass {
        width: {size};
        height: {size};
        fill: {color}
    }
</style>
```

The issue is that even if conceptually it seems easy, I can't find any reliable way of doing this: `dynamicClass` can't be filled with attribute values like `{size}`

I also tried lile this:

```
.dynamicClass {
    width: var(--size, '24px');
    height: var(--size, '24px');
    fill: var(--color, 'white')
}
```

Then using it with style like follows

```
<span class='dynamicClass' style={`--size=${size};--color={color}`}>
```

Which is already a lot more error prone coding style
But I get these errors (in webstorm):

> cannot resolve size custom property

> cannot resolve color custom property

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm does not now how to analyse the code you are writing but it's still working. For that reason, when you do that, you might want to deactivate some warnings or lower errors.

The approach you used with `style=""` is the right one. You can also define the properties with the [`style:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property) this way: `style:--size={size}` which is a shorter way to write it.

Depending of your use case, you can also define a (color) props as a classname. That's super useful when a props is responsible for more than one css property (a button theme for example):

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let color: "red" | "orange" = "red";
  export let size: 10 | 12 | 14 = 12;
</script>

<div class="{color} size-{size}">
  Hello world
</div>

<style>
  .red {
    /* ... */
  }

  .orange {
    /* ... */
  }

  .size-10 {
    /* ... */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer contains interesting ideas. I'd like the user to pick the colors he wants and the sizes he wants, so I cannot use your approach, that would be very verbose.
Thanks for the shorter syntax too :-)

Comment: you can use a combination of string unions when necessary and strings otherwise ;)